# Evaluate signal power between two amplifiers

Tags: amplifier, power-electronics, noise, signal, signal-theory

Let's consider this cascade of amplifiers:

[image]

Consider the intermediate node, and suppose there our signal has voltage Vx.

How can I evaluate that signal power (for instance to calculate the SNR, supposing noise power is known)?

In fact, Power is $$V×I = V^2/R$$, where R is ths load resistor. But the load resistor is infinite (and current is 0) because ideally the following amplifier has infinite input impedance.

Should I conclude that ideally there is no signal power? It seems quite strange. How can I evaluate the SNR in such a case?

I have often seen people using the signal theory definition of power, which is simply the square of voltage. But how can this analysis be effective if we don't consider the load resistor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How can I evaluate the SNR in such a case?*

The signal power is \$V_{SIG}^2/R\$

The noise power is \$V_{NOISE}^2/R\$

So, when you take the ratio (aka signal to noise ratio or SNR) the resistance \$R\$ cancels and you are left with: -

$$SNR = \dfrac{V_{SIG}^2}{V_{NOISE}^2}$$

Comment: So, this is the reason why we consider only the square of voltage in signal theory, correct? The resistor value, which is necessary to evaluate the physical dissipated power, is not essential to evaluate the SNR

Comment: @Kinka-Byo correct.